# Is it possible to define a custom error when accessing blobs from the Azure Blob Service using Shared Access Signatures?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a client application that displays images retrieved from blob storage. The blobs are protected by SAS signatures. When access to the blob expires the blob service returns an error message as follows..

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:399b5e5d-d01e-0022-0813-cb9080000000 Time:2020-01-14T19:45:06.9253703Z
    </Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signed expiry time [Fri, 22 Nov 2019 11:27:07 GMT] must be after signed start time [Tue, 14 Jan 2020 19:45:06 GMT]
    </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Is it possible to customise this error message returned by the blob service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you use an API to serve the blobs, you won't be able to intercept/change the response from Azure Storage Service.

Comment: thought that might be the case. :(  If no one comes up with anything better I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Nattrass - there's really nothing better: the error message comes from Azure itself. Your SAS token either works or it doesn't. The only way to control any type of response is to use your own API, as already stated in the answer.